# Array with dropdowns in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Good Afternoon everyone.

I've tried to search it, but either I'm searching for a wrong thing or there is no answer to that yet. I'm trying to make a list in knockout with a list of drop-downs, and when those drop-down values change, the corresponding value in the list needs to be updated. Here is my current "vision" of that, which doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lypmnspz/6/

Here is the code from Fiddle:

```js
function pageModel(){
  var self = this
  
  // Create an observalbe array of options
  self.languages = ko.observableArray(["English","English","English"]);
  
    // Languages
  self.availableLanguages = ko.observableArray(["English", "Spanish", "German", "Russian"]);
  
  
   
} 

ko.applyBindings(new pageModel());
```

```html
<h4>When I update it here</h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: languages">
    <li><select data-bind="options: $parent.availableLanguages, value: $data"></select></li>
</ul>


<h4>I want to see the update here</h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: languages">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone suggest something? Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to identify the languages preferred by the user or languages the user knows? I am trying to understand what you are trying to get out. You can bind the selection of the drop down to an observable array and display the observable array below. The values of the drop downs can be static or come from another observable array.

Comment: I have a list of languages in the database. User puts primary language and set of subsequent languages (order matters). User can select each subsequent language from the list of available languages. User can have overlapping languages as well. Say P: English, S1: Spanish, S2: English, where P is Primary and S is secondary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need another data model - let's call it a `LanguageSelection`:

```js
var LanguageSelection,
    PageModel,
    pageModel;

LanguageSelection = function LanguageSelection() {
  this.language = ko.observable();
};

PageModel = function PageModel(){
  this.availableLanguages = ko.observableArray([
    "English",
    "Spanish",
    "German",
    "Russian"
  ]);
  
  this.languageSelections = ko.observableArray([]);
} 

pageModel = new PageModel();

pageModel.languageSelections.push( new LanguageSelection() );
pageModel.languageSelections.push( new LanguageSelection() );
pageModel.languageSelections.push( new LanguageSelection() );

ko.applyBindings( pageModel );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h4>When I update it here</h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: languageSelections">
    <li>
      <select data-bind="options: $parent.availableLanguages, value: language"></select>
    </li>
</ul>


<h4>I want to see the update here</h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: languageSelections">
    <li data-bind="text: language"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. I didn't think of going with another model. Thanks a lot. I updated a fiddle with your solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lypmnspz/11/

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with ugly solution, but it works. There should be more elegant way. Here is the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lypmnspz/10/

HTML

```
<h4>When I update it here</h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: languages">
    <li><select data-bind="options: $parent.availableLanguages, value: $data, event: {change: $parent.updateOtherLanguage}, attr: {id: 'langopt-'+$index() }"></select></li>
</ul>


<h4>I want to see the update here</h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: languages">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
function pageModel(){
  var self = this

  // Create an observalbe array of options
  self.languages = ko.observableArray([ko.observable("English"),ko.observable("English"),ko.observable("English")]);

    // Languages
  self.availableLanguages = ko.observableArray(["English", "Spanish", "German", "Russian"]);

    self.updateOtherLanguage = function(lang, event){

       // console.log(event.target.id.split('-')[1],event.target.value)
        self.languages()[Number(event.target.id.split('-')[1])]((event.target.value))
    }


} 

ko.applyBindings(new pageModel());
```

Comment: I would think you could pass the index in the change function like this: change: $parent.updateOtherLanguage($index)

Comment: Not really, but you can wrap it in inline function and change parameters. So instead of $parent.pdateOtherLanguage($index) do something like that: event: {change: function(){$parent.updateOtherLanguage($index, $data)}}

http://jsfiddle.net/Lypmnspz/10/